# Duvida ponteiros em C

Tags: c

tenho um numero inteiro `n`que desejo quebrar(separar seus digitos) e armazenar em um vetor, porém meu código não funciona... o que estou errando?

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define DIM1 3
#define DIM2 3
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<math.h>

int* retorna_quebrado(int a,int &p){

    int* vet;
    int i=0;

    while(a>0){
        vet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        vet[i]=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        i++;
    }

    p=i;
    return vet;
}

int main(){

    int n;
    int p;
    int* vet = retorna_quebrado(n,p);

    scanf("%d",&n);        

    for(int i=0 ; i<p;i++)
        printf(" \n %d",vet[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de retorno do compilador? Ou qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: adicionei uma entrada e uma saida

Answer (score 1):

O problema está aqui:

```
while(a>0){
    vet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    vet[i]=a%10;
    a=a/10;
    i++;
}
```

Vc está malocando o vetor dentro do laço. Sendo assim cada vez vc está re-malocando o vetor e assim sobrescrevendo o conteúdo, faça assim que funcionará:

```
vet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

while(a>0){
    vet[i]=a%10;
    a=a/10;
    i++;
}
```